# Mail verification in Laravel, redirect to custom route?

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have started to learn Laravel and right now I'm trying to get user authentication to work. I followed the instructions from Laravels official documentation on how to register and verify the account via email.

The suggested route for the verification is:

```
Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', function (EmailVerificationRequest $request) {
    $request->fulfill();
    return redirect('/dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'signed'])->name('verification.verify');
```

My first thought was that it's strange you have to login manually to verify the account, the verification link that is mailed out should contain everything needed to verify the user.

Then I'm thinking it's probably a security measure. The problem is that the user will be confused when clicking a verification link just to get directed to the default login route. Can you redirect to some other route, or include some message, just for the verification purpose, so you can inform the user "Please login to verify your account"?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has route service provider. In this file you can see and modify this line to redirect user to desired path.
Commented lines in this file is:

> /**
> * The path to your application's "home" route.
> *
> * Typically, users are redirected here after authentication.
> *
> * @var string
> */

```
public const HOME = '/dashboard';
```

So, maybe if you change it your problem will be solved.